# How can I set a prototype function without using the new keyword

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In a trivial example of prototype inheritance, I wanted to set the `Person` object as the parent class of `Student` object, but I don't want use the new keyword at the time of setting the prototype for the `Student` class as this would be wrong. But somehow this code doesn't work. Any help?

```
var Person = function(name) {
  var that = this;
  this.name = name;
  var _log = function() {
    console.log("Hello", that.name)
  };
  return {
    log: _log
  };
};

var Student = function(name) { 
  Person.call(this, name);  
  var _getCollegeName = function() {
    console.log("MIT")
  };
  return {
    getCollegeName: _getCollegeName
  };
};

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person);
//Student.prototype = new Person("Soham"); want to avoid this as the value should be passed from child class

var s = new Student("Soham");
s.log();
//s.getCollegeName();
```

Comment: The code doesnt work even if I use the `Student.prototype = new Person("Soham")` instead of `Object.create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `getCollegeName` as a property of `Person()` call, return `Person` object

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  var that = this;
  this.name = name;
  var _log = function() {
    console.log("Hello", that.name)
  };
  return {
    log: _log
  };
};

var Student = function(name) {
  var p = Person.call(this, name);

  var _getCollegeName = function() {
    console.log("MIT")
  };

  p.getCollegeName = _getCollegeName;

  return p
};

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person);
//Student.prototype = new Person("Soham"); want to avoid this as the value should be passed from child class

var s = Student("Soham");
s.log();
s.getCollegeName();
```